# create text blocks with zero pt leading

Tags: spacing

What I want to achieve is a text block with zero or, better, nearly zero leading and with searchable text.

[image: Example:]

The above example is a tikz picture, created with inkscape and exported to tikz.

My own efforts did only lead to something like this, which apparently is not sufficient in any case:

[image: example2]

The source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Courier Std}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\parindent0cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}
\begin{document}
 \fontsize{42}{56}\selectfont
The {\color{DarkRed}pitbull} lies\\
well-behaved and\\
chained /It belc\\
hes and it snore\\
s mutedly in its\\
sleep /A melanch\\
oly muzzle on it\\
s snout.........\\
\end{document}
```

Comment: Change `\color{DarkRed}pitbull` to `\textcolor{DarkRed}{pitbull}`?

Comment: In your first image, what if the p of pitbull and the b of behaved coincide vertically? They will overlap... is that acceptable? Apparently you want a negative lead, instead of a 0pt lead...

Comment: You could set `\lineskiplimit` to some negative value, so that overlapping lines don't push the lines apart, e.g. `\lineskiplimit=-20pt` and set baselineskip to some smaller value e.g. `\fontsize{42}{30}\selectfont`. I don't think that the redefinition of `\baselinestretch` is really senseful.

Comment: Yes, `\lineskiplimit=-20pt` does exactly what I want.

Comment: “which *apparently* is not sufficient in my case” – I’m curious: why “apparently”? Who set the requirement, what’s the rationale?

Comment: In the first place I find it not sufficient because of the inconsistent line spacing. The lines 2 and 3, and 4 and 5 are somehow »glued together«.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a commented code achieving the goal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Courier} % this is what I have
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\noindent\makebox[\textwidth][l]{% we don't want overfull box messages
 \renewcommand{\fontsubfuzz}{\maxdimen}% we don't want spurious messages
 \fontsize{42}{42}\selectfont % compute the text width
 \settowidth{\dimen2}{A}%
 \setlength{\dimen2}{16\dimen2}% 16 glyphs per line
 \parbox{\dimen2}{% start a \parbox
  \settoheight{\dimen0}{/}% measure the height of the tallest character
%  \addtolength{\dimen0}{1pt}% finer adjustment
  \fontsize{42}{\dimen0}\selectfont % set the baseline skip
  \lineskiplimit=-\maxdimen\lineskip=0pt % no lines are too near
  \parfillskip=0pt % paragraphs fill the line
  The \textcolor{DarkRed}{pitbull} lies\par
  well-behaved and\par
  chained /It belc\par
  hes and it snore\par
  s mutedly in its\par
  sleep /A melanch\par
  oly muzzle on it\par
  s snout.........\par
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since you've set the width of the `\parbox` suitably, do you need all those `\par` statements?

Comment: @Mico Just to be sure.

Comment: Your code compiles perfectly -- at least when compiled with MacTeX and MacOS X 10.7.5 -- without the `\par` statements. :-)

Comment: @Mico That's true; but I won't leave to the software decisions that belong to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution. Not sure if it produces what you want. I edited a bit the settings so I can compile it without the required font.

You can adjust the vertical distance between baselines at the `\vskip1.5ex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Courier Std}
%\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\parindent0cm
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0}
\def\crampled#1{\smash{#1}\par\vskip1.5ex}
 \fontsize{42}{56}\selectfont
\crampled{The {\color{red}pitbull} lies}
\crampled{well-behaved and}
\crampled{chained /It belc}
\crampled{hes and it snore}
\crampled{s mutedly in its}
\crampled{sleep /A melanch}
\crampled{oly muzzle on it}
\crampled{s snout.........}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]